# Uncaught ReferenceError: fancybox is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

On my page, I have the scripts loading in this order:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://websitename.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

I noted fancybox was not working, and not giving an error message either. So I go to the console and just type "fancybox" to see if it's loading correctly and I get the message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: fancybox is not defined at :1:1

Anyone know why this might not be not working?

Comment: The fancybox script does not appear to add a global `fancybox` object, but rather one attached to jQuery, i.e., `$.fancybox`. This is [directly from the documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api)...

Answer (score 0):

You're using the jQuery version, so in console just write `$.fancybox` instead of `fancybox`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30627177)